# Conditional Decorator Implementation

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to have conditional decorator. Following is my code:-

```
def int_decorator(func):  # checks whether the args passed is of type int.
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        a, b = args
        if not (isinstance(a, int) and isinstance(b, int)):
            return
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


decorator_mapping = {
    'int': int_decorator
}

class conditional_decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        decorator = decorator_mapping.get(kwargs.get('decorator'))
        if not decorator:
            # Return the function unchanged, not decorated.
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorator(self.func(*args, **kwargs))


@conditional_decorator
def func(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    return(1)

print(func(1, 2, decorator='int'))
```

What I want is if there exist any decorator in `decorator_mapping` that matches the value passed in the `func`, then apply the same decorator on the function, else don't apply any decorator.

The above code works well, when there isn;t any decorator, but fails when a decorator is found. It print's the reference of the `function`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: BTW, this is a very inefficient decorator because in addition to all the usual overhead involved for at least an extra function call, it must repeat the decoratoring process every time the target function is called instead of just once after the target function is defined. I suggest you avoid using it even though you now know simple "fix" it needs.

Comment: How would you then define a conditional decorator?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Move the conditional branch to `__init__`, like `self.final_func = decorator(func) if decorator_mapping.get(kwargs.get('decorator')) else func`

Comment: Could you please indent it properly, rather post it as an answer. It would very helpful and clear to the audience.

Comment: PythonEnthusiast: Making in more efficient depends on your intent. The way you currently have it, the decorator actually desired isn't supplied until the function is called. I suppose in a sense that's very dynamic, but I doubt it's really something required and doing it like that incurs a significant runtime overhead. Would the value of the decorator differ from one call to the function to the next? One way to get rid of it would it be to supply the decorator as an argument to `conditional_decorator` instead. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorator accepts a function, returns a function. This line:

```
    return decorator(self.func(*args, **kwargs))
```

should be:

```
    return decorator(self.func)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    decorator = decorator_mapping.get(kwargs.get('decorator'))
    if not decorator:
        # Return the function unchanged, not decorated.
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator(self.func)(*args, **kwargs)
```

You want to decorate the function, then call the decorated version of it.